# Sum of series with cosines

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove this:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{8 \over \left(\,2n - 1\,\right)^{2}\pi^{2}}\,
\sin\left(\,\left[\,2n - 1\,\right]\,{\pi x \over 2}\,\right)
\sin\left(\,\left[\,2n - 1\,\right]\,{\pi z \over 2}\,\right) = \min\left\{x, z\right\}
$$

I got this: 
$$ \frac{8}{\pi ^ 2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} \cos((2n -1)\frac{\pi (x - z)}{2}) - \frac{8}{\pi ^ 2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} \cos((2n -1)\frac{\pi (x + z)}{2})$$

But now I'm completely stuck. Can anybody please help me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I think the index of the sums should be $n$ instead of $i$?

Comment: are $x,z\ge0$ ?

Comment: Yes, they are. $x$ and $z$ are defined in [0, 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Big Hint:**

Integrating the negative of
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}
&=\mathrm{Im}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{inx}}{n}\right)\\
&=-\mathrm{Im}\left(\log(1-e^{ix})\right)\\
&=\frac{x}{2|x|}(\pi-|x|)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^2}=\frac{2\pi^2-6\pi|x|+3x^2}{12}\tag{2}
$$
and subtracting $\frac14$ of $(2)$ at $2x$, which is the even terms of $(2)$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2nx)}{4n^2}=\frac{\pi^2-6\pi|x|+6x^2}{24}\tag{3}
$$
we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos((2n-1)x)}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2-2\pi|x|}8\tag{4}
$$
for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$.

Next, recall that $\min(x,y)=\dfrac{x+y-|x-y|}2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!!
I am trying to figure out the expression for $\operatorname{Im}(\log(1-\exp(ix)))$ I have to solve $\arctan(\frac{-\sin(x)}{1 - \cos(x)})$, right? I obtain $\frac{\pi - x}{2}$. Could you please explain to me why you add the sign of x to the $\pi$ term?
Thanks again, this is so helpful!!

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ is an odd function of $x$. The sign trickery is there simply to make the result an odd function.

Comment: Ah, ok I got it! Thank you very much!